# Mongoose Returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

I'm working on express-typescript-moongose, where user wanted to verify via email.
Mongoose return the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

    at new CustomError (/app/src/utils/response/error.ts:15:18)

    at /app/src/controllers/user.controller.ts:105:25

    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

    at fulfilled (/app/src/controllers/user.controller.ts:5:58)

    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

on the following query

```
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
            confirmUserToken: req.params.token,
            confirmUserExpires: { $gt: new Date() },
            status: "pending",
        }, {
            status: "active",
            confirmUserToken: null,
            confirmUserExpires: null,
        }, {
                new: true,
                runValidators: true,
                rawResult: true,
                debug: true,
        });
```

it's working fine on first query, but once user is verified and try to fetch the same query it's started giving the error instead of returning no object found.

```
try{
    const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
        confirmUserToken: req.params.token,
        confirmUserExpires: { $gt: new Date() },
        status: "pending",
    }, {
        status: "active",
        confirmUserToken: null,
        confirmUserExpires: null,
    }, {
            new: true,
            runValidators: true,
            rawResult: true,
            debug: true,
    });

    if(!result.value) {
        const err = new CustomError(400, "General", "Token is invalid or expired", null);
        return next(err);
    }
    res.customSuccess(200, "User verified successfully", {user: result.value});
} catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    const error = new CustomError(500, "Application", "Error while doing some user operation", err);
    return next(error);
}
```

it's working fine when it's find the document, but once this document is modified and try to fetch the same query, instead of returning value===null, it's started giving the error.

Comment: `at /app/src/controllers/user.controller.ts:105:25`

Comment: result return ```{

  lastErrorObject: { n: 0, updatedExisting: false },

  value: null,

  ok: 1

}``` but still get the same error on ```if(result.value===null) {
            const err = new CustomError(400, "General", "Token is invalid or expired", null);
            return next(err);
        }```